# Use form value in other pages

Tags: php, html, sql, wordpress

i'm making a web project and I have a lot of troubles passing values between webpages and phps. I'm kindly new with php so, be patient.

My problem is:

I have a HTML wordpress page with a form. In this form, I create several checkboxes to check db rows and you can add, edit or delete if you check it and use the buttons. I manage the add and the delete but i have problems with Edit.

So, here is the code where you can see the db entries and the options of add, edit and delete:

```
<strong>Aquí puede ver los ejercicios profesor</strong>

[insert_php]

global $wpdb;

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM ejercicio WHERE 1";

$resultado = $wpdb->get_results( $consulta );

echo "<table><td>";

echo '<form action="http://localhost/wordpress/profesor/profesor-subir-ejercicios"><input type="submit" value="Nuevo"/></form>';
echo "</td><td>";
echo '<form name="boton" method="post" action="/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/borro.php"><input type="submit" name="editar" value="Editar" />';
echo "</td><td>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="borrar" value="Borrar" />';
echo "</td></table>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>";
echo "<strong><u>Ejercicios </u></strong>";
echo "</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach ( $resultado as $fila ):
echo "<tr><td>";
$datos= $fila->Nombre;
echo $datos;
echo "</td><td>";
echo '<input id="borro" type="checkbox" name="marcar[]" value="'.$datos.'"/>';
echo "</td></tr>";
endforeach; 
echo '</form>';
echo "</table>";
[/insert_php]
```

I need to check the checkboxes of "marcar[]" if I go with the form to EDIT or DELETE. With those buttons I go to PHP file borro.php:

```
<?php

include_once('../../wp-load.php');
include_once('../../wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;

if(!empty($_POST['marcar'])){

if($_POST["editar"]) {
foreach($_POST['marcar'] as $selected)
 header('Location: http://localhost/wordpress/profesor/profesor-editar/');
}

if($_POST["borrar"]) { 

foreach($_POST['marcar'] as $selected)
   {
   $wpdb->delete( 'ejercicio', array( 'Nombre' => $selected));
   }
header('Location: http://localhost/wordpress/profesor/profesor-ejercicios/');
}
} 
?>
```

You can see that I check the checked options and if I pressed DELETE i will delete the rows. But If I press EDIT I will go to editar webpage where I want the user update the fields of only one selected in the checkboxes.

```
<strong>Aquí podrá editar el ejercicio profesor</strong>

[insert_php]

global $wpdb;
echo '<form action="/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/edito.php" method="post">';

echo "Nombre <br>";

echo '<input type="text" name="nombrecaja"><br>';

echo "Enunciado <br>";

echo '<textarea name="enunciadocaja" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br>';

echo "Solución <br>";

echo '<textarea name="solucioncaja" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea> <br>';

echo '<input type="submit" value="Subir ejercicio" /></form>';

[/insert_php]
```

So, I want to get the row of the checkbox checked, to fill the input with the database information and the user can update it. I think I will not have problem checking the database but I don´t know how to know what row was checked (what row needs to be updated to make the query). Basically, I dont know how to check the checked values stored in marcar[] in the Edit webpage to update it.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to use a ``$_SESSION`` variable in order to keep track of your datas. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: I added   `session_start();  $_SESSION['dato'] = $_POST['marcar'];` in the php before redirect with header. And after that, in the html file I put: `session_start(); echo $_SESSION['dato']['0'];` . I can see the value right!!!! but the session_start() fails with WARNING: SESSION_START(): CANNOT SEND SESSION CACHE LIMITER – HEADERS ALREADY SENT . But the data is there!!!

Comment: @SugusTHC, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_SESSION` and put `session_start()` at the top of all of your code and it should resolve the warning problem. When I said at the top of your code it means that `session_start()` should be the first line of code in the file.

You can read more about php sessions [here](http://php.net/manual/ro/reserved.variables.session.php).

Comment: I added session_start(); $_SESSION['dato'] = $_POST['marcar']; in the php before redirect with header. And after that, in the html file I put: session_start(); echo $_SESSION['dato']['0']; . I can see the value right!!!! but the session_start() fails with WARNING: SESSION_START(): CANNOT SEND SESSION CACHE LIMITER – HEADERS ALREADY SENT . But the data is there!!!

Comment: @SugusTHC . Ok. So the warning still appears? Or what seems do be the problem now?

Comment: I put the session_start() on the top, after the [insert_php], and still appearing the warning :/ Its curious because the ECHO of the value works right after that warning.

Comment: @SugusTHC Put it to be the first line in the code. Above any `html` and `php` code.

Comment: @SugusTHC it `session_start()` always needs to be called before any HTTP headers are sent. That's why it needs to be the first line in the code.

Comment: Finnally worked! I needed to put the session_start in the header.php of the theme! Was horrible :/ Thanks a lot for your interest

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna use the sessions variables through your pages, your must begin every pages with the session directives, **even before any HTML or PHP code that you wrote before**.

```
<?php

  session_start(); /* repeat this line in any others files that should communicate with this page through session superglobals */

?>

<strong>Aquí puede ver los ejercicios profesor</strong>

[insert_php]

global $wpdb;

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM ejercicio WHERE 1";

$resultado = $wpdb->get_results( $consulta );

echo "<table><td>";

echo '<form action="http://localhost/wordpress/profesor/profesor-subir-ejercicios"><input type="submit" value="Nuevo"/></form>';
echo "</td><td>";
echo '<form name="boton" method="post" action="/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/borro.php"><input type="submit" name="editar" value="Editar" />';
echo "</td><td>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="borrar" value="Borrar" />';
echo "</td></table>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>";
echo "<strong><u>Ejercicios </u></strong>";
echo "</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach ( $resultado as $fila ):
echo "<tr><td>";
$datos= $fila->Nombre;
echo $datos;
echo "</td><td>";
echo '<input id="borro" type="checkbox" name="marcar[]" value="'.$datos.'"/>';
echo "</td></tr>";
endforeach; 
echo '</form>';
echo "</table>";
[/insert_php]
```

Next, you'll have to treat your sessions datas in order to use them.

Also note that if you're heading through different page, you must first close the session flux.

[PHP : sessions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: With that code before my code makes no warning appear, but, in the other hand, the value that i want to pass is not there. I dunno :/

Comment: Could be the close because I change of page, how i use that?

Comment: I showed you here how a session can be start. Now you can work on implementing it on your whole project. You just have to register the correct variables in your ``$_SESSION`` variable for the next season to be used.